# Limit a mesh so it doesn't collide with or enter another mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm wondering if it's possible to limit a mesh so it doesn't collide with another mesh. I'd like to be able to move a mesh around the 3D view and have it *stop* moving along that axis when it touches another mesh (of my choosing, preferably). Is this possible?

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for the other question!

Comment: AFAIK it's only possible when having Blender animate things, like when creating a cloth animation.

Comment: @jwenting That should be a feature... but I imagine it would be hard to implement.